# Paypal intergration - Payment not processable error in ionic3?

Tags: paypal, ionic3, paypal-sandbox

I am working on the paypal integration to my ionic app,…Happily i could easily implement the paypal with static value, but when I tried to dynamic value it shows an error.
Payment not processable in console.

```js
continueSubscription(){
    //initialize payment......
    this.payPal.init({
       PayPalEnvironmentProduction: '',
       PayPalEnvironmentSandbox: 'XXXXXX'
     }).then(() => {
      var data = this.paymentAmount;

      // Environments: PayPalEnvironmentNoNetwork, PayPalEnvironmentSandbox, PayPalEnvironmentProduction  
      this.payPal.prepareToRender('PayPalEnvironmentSandbox', new PayPalConfiguration({})).then(() => {
        console.log(this.selectedValue);
        var payment = new PayPalPayment(this.selectedValue.amount, this.selectedValue.currency_type, 'Description', this.selectedValue.descryption);
        this.payPal.renderSinglePaymentUI(payment).then((res) => {
          // Successfully paid
          this.paymentResponse = res;
        }, (error) => {
            console.log(error);  
          // Error or render dialog closed without being successful
        });
      }, () => {
        // Error in configuration
      });
    }, () => {
      // Error in initialization, maybe PayPal isn't supported or something else
    });
  }
```

below share the updated ts code and selectedValue is object in which we have pass dynamic data and i pass following object to payment:

```
      amount: "200"
      bnCode: "PhoneGap_SP"
      currency: "INR"
      details: undefined
      intent: "Health Record With Conditioncjn dfgh"
      shortDescription: "Description"
```

Please team tell me how to fix above error ?

Comment: Hello,
I am facing the same error. Can you help me out to solve the same?

Comment: hi,actually in my case i have passed wrong amount value like..decimal value is sent in param?

Answer (score 0):

Did you make sure that `this.selectedValue.amount` is a string?
PayPal expects the amount as a string, no number / int is accepted.

What does your console say if you execute `console.log(this.selectedValue.amount);`?

You could also try to use single quotes instead of double quotes.

Comment: Yes I have passed amount in string and still I am getting the same error. Can you please let me what else can be tried and checked?